# Remove Fragment from MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin

I was able to make a fragment as below

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment2, ConsumeFragment.newInstance(consumerTitle)).commit()
```

and my ConsumeFragment Class

```
class ConsumeFragment : Fragment()
   companion object {
        const val titleKey = "consumeTitle"
        fun newInstance(title: String): ConsumeFragment {
            val frag = ConsumeFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString(titleKey, title)
            frag.arguments = bundle
            return frag
        }
```

Now I am trying to remove the fragment by clicking the button as below

```
binding.killConsumeBut.setOnClickListener{
Log.d("XXX", "click KillConsumerButton")
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(ConsumeFragment()).commit()}
```

However, it doesn't remove the fragment. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for `remove()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#remove(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)):

> Remove an **existing** fragment

(emphasis added)

You are creating a new fragment instance via `ConsumeFragment()`, then are trying to remove it. That is not going to work.

Instead, hold onto the `ConsumeFragment` instance that you added previously, and use `remove()` with it. Or, find the fragment in your `FragmentManager` (e.g., [via `findFragmentById()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#findFragmentById(int))), then call `remove()` with it.

Comment: hold onto the ConsumeFragment instance that you added previously. Do i set this to a variable? Like val a = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment2, ConsumeFragment.newInstance(consumerTitle)).commit()?

Comment: @CocaCola35: "Do i set this to a variable?" -- perhaps, or a property in the activity class. In your first code snippet, you have `ConsumeFragment.newInstance(consumerTitle)`. That is creating the fragment. You could hold onto that fragment, then later pass it to `remove()`. IOW, the *same object* that you pass to `add()` should be passed to `remove()`.

Comment: I tried this supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2)).commit(). But I got error: Type mismatch: inferred type is Fragment? but Fragment was expected.

Comment: @CocaCola35: That is because `findFragmentById()` may return `null`. If it does, there is nothing for you to remove, so you could skip the whole transaction.

Comment: How do I fix that? Sorry I'm very slow

Comment: @CocaCola35: `supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2)?.let { supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(it).commit() }` should work

Comment: Ok the frame got removed. But then the app crashed lol. I think there's a bug somewhere. Thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate it.